# Do stuff with multiple files when uploading them using node-formidable with Express

Tags: node.js, express

Uploading files with node-formidable on Express is as simple as this

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    // do something with req.files
});
```

The files are now saved

The form: (multiple="multiple" is a HTML5 feature that allows users to select multiple files to upload)

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload">
    <input type="text" name="title"/>
    <input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"/>
    <input type="submit" value="upload" id="s3form_submit"/>
</form>
```

If i add this line to the upload code

```
console.log(req.files.upload.path);
```

When uploading one file, the path shows up in the console. But when I upload more than one file it just says undefined in the console.
How do I get the log stuff for each file? Using a for loop?

The node-formidable example on GitHub logs every file when you upload several: https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/blob/master/example/upload.js (I tried using this code in Express, didn’t work)
It does exactly what I want, but how do I do this in an Express app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It works by moving the line below to the bottom of the app.configure function. Read about the importance of order regarding middleware in Express here: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#middleware

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({ uploadDir:__dirname + '/public/uploads' }));
```

And by using this handler:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
    files = [],
    fields = [];
    form.on('field', function(field, value) {
        fields.push([field, value]);
    })
    form.on('file', function(field, file) {
        console.log(file.name);
        files.push([field, file]);
    })
    form.on('end', function() {
        console.log('done');
        res.redirect('/forms');
    });
    form.parse(req);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

So `req.files` could be an array. Try doing `console.log(req.files)` in the handler and see what it looks like... But I think you're better off just doing it like in their example. You can get it to work by just removing the `../test/common` require at the top and changing the constants to static values (eg instead of `TEST_TMP` use `__dirname + '/uploads'`).

The handler:

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
    files = [],
    fields = [];

form.uploadDir = __dirname + '/uploads';

form
  .on('field', function(field, value) {
    console.log(field, value);
    fields.push([field, value]);
  })
  .on('file', function(field, file) {
    console.log(field, file);
    files.push([field, file]);
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('-> upload done');
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('received fields:\n\n '+util.inspect(fields));
    res.write('\n\n');
    res.end('received files:\n\n '+util.inspect(files));
  });
form.parse(req);
```

The files are now in `__dirname + '/uploads'` named as per the output on the console (and to the response, as you can see in the `end` handler).