# Formidable w Express - Inconsistent results when uploading audio

Tags: node.js, docker, upload, formidable

I'm trying to upload an audio file to a temp directory in my project. A file gets created as expected, but 90% of the time the audio cannot be opened in VScode. I cannot find a reason why it suddenly decides to work sometimes.

I have a docker image based on:
`FROM nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.11-nodejs20`

I'm using the Formidable module:
`npm install formidable`

To test the API, I've been using postman to create a POST request with form-data.
The key is audio and value is an .mp3 file.

What I've tried:

Too many versions of this to post. This was the most successful.
`router.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {

```
// Create a Formidable form and enable multiple file uploads
const form = formidable({ multiples: false, uploadDir: 'temp', keepExtensions: true });

// Parse the incoming request
form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error parsing form:', err);
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    // Assuming the file field name is 'file'
    const file = files.audio;
    if (!file) {
        return res.status(400).send('No file uploaded');
    next(err);
    return;
    }
}
```

});`

I also tried running code directly from the examples directory in the [Formidable git repo](https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable/blob/master/examples/with-express.js) and other relevant questions on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124099/do-stuff-with-multiple-files-when-uploading-them-using-node-formidable-with-expr)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by adding this to my app.js:

`app.use(express.json()); app.use(express.urlencoded());`

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720765/formidable-doesnt-form-parse-when-uploading-a-file-in-nodejs?rq=2)

and downgrading my docker image to:
`python3.10-nodejs20`

There also must be an issue with one of the audio files I was testing